# Prove that det(AB)=det(A)det(B) using tensors

Tags: matrices, determinant, tensor-products, tensors

Prove that det(AB)=det(A)det(B) , were A,B and AB are 3x3 matrices using tensors.

Given that:
detA=$\epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3
k}$ and that $\epsilon_{ijk}a_{pi}a_{qj}a_{rk}=\epsilon_{pqr}detA$ 
I don't see how this two facts combined allow me to find the determinant of the product of two matrices.

Comment: "Given that: detA=$\epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{1j}a_{1k}$" Sorry but who *gave* you that? Note that the RHS does not depend on $a_{ij}$ for $i\geqslant2$...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that expression as it is just the determinant expressed using Einstein summation convention. @Did

Comment: Please check what you wrote: there is no way using three times $$1$$ as the first index of $$a_{ij}$$ can refer to the determinant. Assuming matrices of size 3 (which is not mentioned in your post), Einstein summation would read $$\det(A)=\epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k}$$

Comment: @Did thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed it already.

Comment: "Already", as in, 2 hours later... Anyway, are we to understand that your matrices are only 3x3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about the problem I realised that the product of a matrix is expressed as $(AB)_{ij}=a_{ip}b_{pj}$ substituting this in the determinant formula above and expanding will give the answer which is then trivial by inspection.