# How to prove $\det{AB}=\det{A}\det{B}$ with Leibniz formula in terms of Levi-Civita symbol and Einstein summation notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tensors, index-notation

> Prove that $\det{AB}=\det{A}\det{B}$ with Leibniz formula in terms of Levi-Civita symbol and Einstein summation notation

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280384/prove-that-detab-detadetb-using-tensors) is a similar question asked 6 years ago. The OP answered in the question that "expanding will give the answer which is then trivial by inspection", but I still can't understand why it is "trivial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
C=AB
\end{align}
then we have that
\begin{align}
c_{ij} = a_{ik}b_{kj}.
\end{align}
Next, notice that
\begin{align}
\det(C) =&\, \epsilon_{ijk}c_{1i}c_{2j}c_{3k}\\
=&\, \epsilon_{ijk}a_{1p}b_{pi}a_{2q}b_{qj}a_{3r}b_{rk}\\
=&\, a_{1p}a_{2q}a_{3r}\epsilon_{ijk}b_{pi}b_{qj}b_{rk}\\
=&\, a_{1p}a_{2q}a_{3r}\epsilon_{pqr}\det(B)\\
=&\, \det(A^T)\det(B) = \det(A)\det(B).
\end{align}